# Difference between Sails.lift() and Sails.load()

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sails.js

I'm trying to make some test on a Sails app. So beforeEach test I need to lift my Sails like this :

```
// Reset database before each test
beforeEach(function(done) {

  // Get instance of Sails
  sails = Sails();

  // Lift the app
  sails.lift({
    // configuration for testing purposes
    hooks:{
      // Don't call Grunt
      grunt:false
    }
  }, function(err, server) {

    if (err) return done(err);

    done(err, server);
  });
});
```

But I see that is a little slowly. So I saw some people use Sails.load(). Does really have a difference between Sails.lift and Sails.load ? if yes, which one ?

Thank's !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sails.lift() = Sails.load() + initialize();

The response is here :

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/tree/master/lib/app#user-content-faq

Hope it will serve.